# How to round up a number with 2 decimal points in jQuery after being multiplied

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use JQuery to round up the total number. Since the number is a currency, I want it to round up with 2 decimal points

```js
$('.total').text( parseFloat($('.itemOne').text()) * ($('.itemTwo').text())).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemOne" style="display: none;">12</div>
<div class="itemTwo" style="display: none;" >0.6</div>    
Total:<div class="total"></div>
```

Current result:
Total:
7.199999999999999

Needed result:
Total:
7.20

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcr0qknx/

Comment: Did you see that you have an error in console, right?

Comment: Surely your research on this turned up some solutions. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```js
var total = parseFloat($('.itemOne').text()) * parseFloat($('.itemTwo').text());
$('.total').text(Math.round(total * 100) / 100);
```